# Append a JSON string to a file which already contains JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I’m trying to append a JSON string into a JSON file which already has JSON data.

**/public/temp.json:**

```
{
  "IPBlock":"1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16",
  "IPAddress":"1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,1.2.3.6,1.2.128.1",
  "device":"device1,device2,device3,device1"
}
```

I want to add a new record to this file:

```
{
  "IPBlock":"1.2.0.0",
  "IPAddress":"1.2.3.4",
  "device":"device21"
}
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without first converting the JSON to a Ruby Hash.

```
current_json = JSON.parse('{
  "IPBlock":"1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16",
  "IPAddress":"1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,1.2.3.6,1.2.128.1",
  "device":"device1,device2,device3,device1"
}')

new_json = JSON.parse('{
  "IPBlock":"1.2.0.0",
  "IPAddress":"1.2.3.4",
  "device":"device21"
}')

current_json.each do |key, value|
  current_json[key] << ",#{new_json[key]}"
end
```

This outputs the following JSON:

```
{
    "IPBlock": "1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0/16,1.2.0.0",
    "IPAddress": "1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,1.2.3.6,1.2.128.1,1.2.3.4",
    "device": "device1,device2,device3,device1,device21"
}
```

It's interesting that your values for each JSON key are one comma-delimited string. If your initial JSON values were [arrays](https://www.json.com/json-array), you could actually just append it to each array:

```
current_json.each do |key, value|
  current_json[key] << new_json[key]
end
```

It would also make both your code and JSON data a little cleaner.